# Is it safe to set Created By and Modified By fields as non-read-only?

Tags: read-only

Are there risks to set Created By or Modified By as non-read-only and leave them be as read-only fields?

(I am considering this for a web Service based solution where the current user credentials cannot be used)

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to *make* them read-only? The question says setting them as non-read-only, but the description mentions risks of setting them as read-only, just clarifying.  OOTB they're just fields, however you cannot edit these fields in the UI; but it can be done programmatically in a number of ways.  Unless I misunderstood your question, see [Can we update the values of "Created By", "Modified By" columns in SharePoint lists ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/03/14/can-we-update-the-values-of-created-by-modified-by-columns-in-sharepoint-lists.aspx) or [Updating Created and Modified information for Files in a SharePoint Document Library](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2009/04/03/updating-created-and-modified-information-in-sharepoint-document-libraries.aspx).  If I misunderstood I apologize.

Comment: I mean  to set them from read-only to not-read-only. Yes this can be done programmatically. I mean issues in, say, migrations. The links are for SharePoint server-side. We need to Access SharePoint via web services remotely.